# how to override template breadcrumb.tpl in prestashop module

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I need to use my own breadcrumb.tpl file in prestashop template only if module active. 
I know about displayOverrideTemplate hook, but i need to override non-controller tpl file - breadcrumb.tpl

Comment: You can not do this by using **displayOverrideTemplate** this hook. Because breadcrumb.tpl  included by header.tpl. header.tpl can include any other naming tpl file for breadcrumb.

Comment: That's why i asked how to override breadcrumb.tpl...

Comment: But i think its not possible.